# UseDispatch hook react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dispatch

Help me to understand.  i use useDispatch but i don't change the state.  what am I doing wrong.  I read a lot of information, but I can not understand what is my mistake.

i tried other hooks but nothing works.

I've marked up the code below to make it clear. Reducer, action, store, component

component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {loginAction, passwordAction} from "../action/userAction";
import storeConfiguration from "../store/storeConfiguration";
import {changeLogin, changePassword} from "../utils/Const";


const Login = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const stateUser = storeConfiguration.getState()

    const senData = () => {
        localStorage.setItem(stateUser.login, stateUser.password)
        console.log(storeConfiguration.getState());
        let keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
        for(let key of keys) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${localStorage.getItem(key)}`);
            dispatch(loginAction())
            dispatch(passwordAction())
        }
    }

    function clear() {
        localStorage.clear();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Please, enter Username</p>
            <input placeholder={'your login'}
                   onChange={e => changeLogin( e.target.value)}/>
            <p>Please, enter Password</p>
            <input placeholder={'your password'}
                   onChange={e => changePassword( e.target.value)}/>
            <p></p>
            <button onClick={()=>senData()}>Enter</button>
            <button onClick={()=>clear()}>clear</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

action:

```
export const LOGIN = 'loginAction'
export const PASSWORD = 'passwordAction'

export const loginAction = login =>(
    {
        type: LOGIN,
        payload: login
    })

export const passwordAction = password =>(
    {
        type: PASSWORD,
        payload: password
    })
```

reducer:

```
import {LOGIN, PASSWORD} from "../action/userAction";

function userReducer (state, action)
{
    switch (action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            return {...state, login: action.payload }
        case PASSWORD:
            return {...state, password: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default userReducer
```

store:

```
import userReducer from "../reducer/userReducer";
import { legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux'



const initialState =
    {
            login:'',
            password: '',
    }

const store = createStore(userReducer, initialState)

export default store
```

const:

```
export const currentLogin = 'Admin'
export const currentPassword = '12345'

export const changeLogin = (login) => {
    return login
}
export const changePassword = (password) => {
    return password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this two lines of code

```
dispatch(loginAction())
dispatch(passwordAction())
```

You haven't passed any payload, so nothing can be changed actually

Comment: if I create a constant object with login and password fields, and use the changeLogin and ChangePassword function to put values in it. and then I will pass the values from the constant to UseDispatch, will it work this way?